# bootstrap modal close on esc without tabindex=-1

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I use form on bootstrap modals, and i use [select2](https://select2.github.io/) in most of my forms, with [bootsrap theme](https://github.com/select2/select2-bootstrap-theme).

My problem is that when on a modal the `tabindex="-1"` is set as it should be the select2 search input field is not functioning.
I have tried out many solution that i found, but non of them work so far.

Most of them suggest to set `z-index` very high of different classes that select2 use.

The current working solution to remove `tabindex="-1"` from the modal, but with this solution modal can't be closed with esc button.

Is there any solution for this?